# Check if attribute has some value via XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have a XML like this:

```
...
<result name="Result" test="xpto" cat="2"/>
<result name="ExecuteTest" test="xpto"/>
<result name="Result" test="xpto" cat="1"/>
<result name="CloseTest" test="xpto"/>
...
```

and my current XSD is this:

```
<xs:element name="result" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="test" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="cat" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I want to validate in my XSD file, if in my XML file the first element `<result>` have the the `value="Result"` and if have the attribute `cat="..."`.   It is possible?

Answer (score 1):

First off, XML cannot have multiple root elements, so wrap your `result` elements in a common single root element:

### XML A

```
<results>
  <result name="Result" test="xpto" cat="2"/>
  <result name="ExecuteTest" test="xpto"/>
  <result name="Result" test="xpto" cat="1"/>
  <result name="CloseTest" test="xpto"/>
</results>
```

Secondly, it's poor XML design to use generic element names with `name` attributes like this.   Instead, consider:

### XML B

```
<results>
  <Result test="xpto" cat="2"/>
  <ExecuteTest test="xpto"/>
  <Result test="xpto" cat="1"/>
  <CloseTest test="xpto"/>
</results>
```

### XSD possibilities:

Finally, decide on one of the above XML designs and whether you're going to use XSD 1.0 or 1.1:

- XSD 1.0 cannot represent your constraint for XML A.
- XSD 1.0 could represent for XML B that all `Result` elements must
  have (required or optional) `cat` attributes with fixed values of
  `2`.
- XSD 1.1 could represent your constraint for XML A with Conditional
  Type Assignment, but would also need assertions to make a statement
  about positioning.
- XSD 1.1 could use assertions alone for XML A or XML B.